# Getting SQLGrammarException with @Query and Localdate

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

Hello everyone so I have this filterDto

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class FilterDto{

    private String status;
    private String author;
    private String content;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate createdOn;

}
```

And I have this Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Entity{

    private String status;
    private String author;
    private String content;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate createdOn;

}
```

and I am sending a filter from the FE to the back-end. I am using Spring Boot with JPA and PostgreSQL as my relational DB.

The repository method is:

```
    @Query("SELECT r "
            + " FROM ResearchRequestEntity r "
            + " WHERE "
            + " (:#{#filter.content} is null OR r.content=:#{#filter.content}) AND "
            + " (:#{#filter.author} is null OR r.author like %:#{#filter.author}%) AND "
            + " (:#{#filter.createdOn} is null OR r.createdOn<=:#{#filter.createdOn}) AND "
            + " (:#{#filter.status} is null OR r.status=:#{#filter.status})"
    )
    Page<ResearchRequestEntity> findByFilter(FilterDto filter, Pageable pageable);
```

Whenever i try to send a date i get back

```
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $5
```

I placed

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

in my properties

and i am getting

```
2021-10-06 20:55:12 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - []
2021-10-06 20:55:12 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - []
2021-10-06 20:55:12 - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - []
2021-10-06 20:55:12 - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [%%]
2021-10-06 20:55:12 - binding parameter [5] as [DATE] - [2021-10-06]
2021-10-06 20:55:12 - binding parameter [6] as [DATE] - [2021-10-06]
2021-10-06 20:55:12 - binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - []
```

I googled and tried many things like adding @Temporal but to no avail. When I am pulling the Object with the `findAll` method it has no problems i do not know why any help is appreciated I am completely stucked

Comment: Not an answer to your question but for your use case (rich filtering based on client input) I would recommend to use [specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) instead.

Comment: It's clear that `@DateTimeFormat` is being ignored, since Jackson is Spring de facto `Serializer`. Either, using `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING , pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")` or define your own Date Serializer.

Comment: Managed to Solve it the problem was the different format that I was tryin to set the filed with the annotation if I use no annotation or @JsonFormat with the proper pattern everything is fine. Thanks for your answers :)